# How to switch tab using for loop in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I struggle with the problem of not being able to switch between tabs using the loop in Selenium WebDriver. I can do this at once, but I need to use the code repeatedly, in a loop.

Here comes the error:

```
"Exception in thread" main "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to locate window"
```

My code can find all the elements, open a link in a new tab, close it. However, it can not perform this operation again with the next element.

Here is my code( I'm using Firefox):

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.className("_4zhc5"));
    int s = allElements.size();
    
    System.out.println("total users to check: " + allElements.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        
        
        
        allElements = driver.findElements(By.className("_4zhc5"));
        String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
        allElements.get(i).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
        
    
        for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
             
        }

         
        
         driver.close();
         Thread.sleep(2000);

    }
```

I also created a prototype page using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzr38xs3/1/). The error appears on the second attempt to execute the code. Just the script does not click on another element called "lovely"

Comment: I think the issue is, you are fetching all the windows(say 5) and switching to some window, doing some stuff and closing that window. Now we will be having only 4 windows, but the list is still having 5 windows. During the second iteration script is trying to switch to the deleted window and throsing err

Comment: I think you are right. I have no idea however how to fix it, it seems to be difficult.

Comment: after dealing with the first element, in first tab for first time, can you continue with next element without closing that tab? Else we need to do the windowhandles again so that it wont have the deleted tab

Comment: I have to close the card immediately after performing some operations, the list may consist of eg 50 links. How to use windowshandles again in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch back to the original window where the links are.

1. Click on one if the links
2. Switch to that tab
3. Close tab
4. Switch back to default window where you are getting the links

Easiest way is to store the "original" window and switch back to that one all the time.
`winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();`

when closing the tab

```
driver.close();
```

`driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore)`

Comment: Thank you for answer and study, a simple solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

/*the second "for loop" will not help you so u should use another logic with another condition it will switch using while loop and hasNext method
try it: */

List allElements = driver.findElements(By.className("_4zhc5"));

```
int s = allElements.size();
System.out.println("total users to check: " + allElements.size());
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    allElements = driver.findElements(By.className("_4zhc5"));
    String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
    allElements.get(i).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
    Set<String>windowat=driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String>itro=windowat.iterator();
    while(itro.hasNext()) {
        String currntpage=itro.next();
        driver.switchTo().window(currntpage);
        String thetitle=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(thetitle); }
```